# Inserting days in a range per group

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a problem that's probably solvable using MultiIndex, reindex and period_range but I don't have an idea how to do this exactly.

I have a following data frame:

```
proj_id   date_from    date_to      some_value
abc1001   2017-10-20   2017-10-21            7
abc1002   2017-10-29   2017-11-03           10
abc1002   2017-09-05   2017-09-07            9
abc1003   2017-09-05   2017-09-05            3
```

I'd like to convert it to have something like this:

```
proj_id   date         some_value
abc1001   2017-10-20            7
abc1001   2017-10-21            7
abc1002   2017-10-29           10
abc1002   2017-10-30           10
abc1002   2017-10-31           10
abc1002   2017-11-01           10
abc1002   2017-11-02           10
abc1002   2017-11-03           10
abc1002   2017-09-05            9
abc1002   2017-09-06            9
abc1002   2017-09-07            9
abc1003   2017-09-05            3
```

So basically I have some date ranges per project with some value and want to generate records for each day between these ranges BUT the ranges are different per project and there can even be many separate ranges per one project.

I thought that if I could somehow manage to construct a MultIindex like so:

```
                    some_value
abc1001 2017-10-20           7
        2017-10-21         NaN
abc1002 2017-09-05           9
        2017-09-06         NaN
        2017-09-07         NaN
        2017-10-29          10
        2017-10-30         NaN
        2017-10-31         NaN
        2017-11-01         NaN
        2017-11-02         NaN
        2017-11-03         NaN
abc1003 2017-09-05           3
```

then I would be able to fill missing values using `DataFrame.fillna(method='ffill')` but the problem is I don't know how to create such index.

Of course this is only a simplified example and in reality the number of projects is large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for reshape DataFrame, then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `first` and last call `ffill`:

*Notice:*

*Solution working if no missing values in data.*

```
df = (df.reset_index()
        .melt(['proj_id','some_value', 'index'], value_name='date')
        .set_index('date')
        .groupby(['proj_id', 'index'])['some_value']
        .resample('d')
        .first()
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .ffill()
        .reset_index()
       )
print (df)
    proj_id       date  some_value
0   abc1001 2017-10-20         7.0
1   abc1001 2017-10-21         7.0
2   abc1002 2017-10-29        10.0
3   abc1002 2017-10-30        10.0
4   abc1002 2017-10-31        10.0
5   abc1002 2017-11-01        10.0
6   abc1002 2017-11-02        10.0
7   abc1002 2017-11-03        10.0
8   abc1002 2017-09-05         9.0
9   abc1002 2017-09-06         9.0
10  abc1002 2017-09-07         9.0
11  abc1003 2017-09-05         3.0
```

Another solution:

```
s = pd.concat([pd.Series(r.Index,pd.date_range(r.date_from, r.date_to)) 
               for r in df.itertuples()])

df1 = df[['proj_id','some_value']].join(pd.Series(s.index, s.values).rename('date'))
print (df1)
   proj_id  some_value       date
0  abc1001           7 2017-10-20
0  abc1001           7 2017-10-21
1  abc1002          10 2017-10-29
1  abc1002          10 2017-10-30
1  abc1002          10 2017-10-31
1  abc1002          10 2017-11-01
1  abc1002          10 2017-11-02
1  abc1002          10 2017-11-03
2  abc1002           9 2017-09-05
2  abc1002           9 2017-09-06
2  abc1002           9 2017-09-07
3  abc1003           3 2017-09-05
```

Comment: I tried your first solution and it produces the correct result but when I tested on a bigger dataset it turned out to be too slow. I haven't tried your second solution but in the meantime I implemented my own which is running fast enough. Anyway, your answer is correct of course.

Answer (score 0):

[jazrael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael) first answer is correct but either I improperly ported his code (because like I said the example was a simplified version of a real problem) or it really has some performance problems. Anyway, I implemented another solution which is working fast enough for me. Posting it here in case someone is interested:

```
non_start_end_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col not in ['date_from', 'date_to']]

rows = []
def process_row(row):
    non_date_row_data = [row[col] for col in non_start_end_cols]
    for day in pd.date_range(start=row['date_from'], end=row['date_to']).to_pydatetime():
        rows.append(non_date_row_data + [day])

_ = df.apply(process_row, axis=1)
new_df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=non_start_end_cols + ['date'])
```

And in case the date periods are overlapping a simple aggragation fixes the situation:

```
groupby_cols = non_start_end_cols.copy()
groupby_cols.append('date')
groupby_cols.remove('some_value')

aggregated = new_df \
    .groupby(groupby_cols) \
    .agg(np.sum) \
    .reset_index()
```